# Python Can't Find Correct Mysqlclient

Tags: python, mysql, django, macos, pip

I'm trying to get mysql up on a new Django project on MacOS. I used pip to intsall it. This is the output from my second attempt so that I could show the install here:

> python3 -m pip install mysqlclient
> Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
> Requirement already satisfied: mysqlclient in /Users/curt/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (1.4.6)

This is my **init**.py file: (the stack overflow editor has dropped the underscores)

```
import mysqlclient

mysqlclient.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

PyCharm is indicating it can't find mysqlclient on line 1 and the message "Package requirement 'mysqlclient==1.4.6' is not satisfied" is displayed.

I tried adding the path shown in the pip install to $PYTONPATH to no effect. Is there somewhere else I should to be setting the location of mysqlclient?

### Update

I opened the Pipenv environment settings and selected add package and selected mysqlclient. The version was 1.4.6. I clicked install package and got a repsonse that the install was successful.

> 3:28 PM   Packages installed successfully: Installed packages: 'mysqlclient'

When I closed the add package dialog. The package did not show in the environment settings dialog. When I closed it I got the same error message as above.

I checked the Pipfile.lock and saw that mysqlclient was in it so I did a sync to see if that would fix the problem. It didn't

When I ran pipenv --where, it pointed to an old django project. I created the current project with PyCharm new project option.

Comment: Did you point PyCharm to the correct virtual environment?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by creating a new interpreter. IIRC, this also created a venv directory in the project. Now, "python3 -m pipenv --where" points to the right project. In addition, mysqlclient appeares as one of the packages. At this point it complained of not being able to run Django. I fixed this by copying the environment variable from the original interpreter.